# how to use azure ad to spring boot auth 2.0 application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, pingfederate

In my project i was previously using ping federate and that has heartbeat which i mention in my .yml file.
for example
heart-beat-uri: https://login-abc.com/pingfederation/heartbeat.ping

any idea that azure uses heartbeat or not?

Comment: You mean Availability check? i.e. there will be a ping to a particular Url in some interval of time?

Comment: Yes I meant Availability check.

Comment: Yes it's there. Go to Application Insight. There will be a Option 'Availability'. There Create a test. Pass your required URL in the specified text box. Give your Interval there at what you want to ping. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Explained in the comment section, please find the reference for the same.

[image: AppInsight Ping test]